# How the following code will work In IE8 for uploading multiple file?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, dom-events

```
<!-- saved from url=(0022)http://internet.e-mail -->
<html>
<style>
  .thumb {
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;

  }
</style>

<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect);

</script>
</html>
```

This code is working fine in Mozila, but its not working in IE8 since IE8 does not support HTML5. What are the required changes can work code in IE8 properly? 
Please provide details.

Comment: What have you tried? Which errors where thrown in the console? What about using the debugger tool? Where is your self contained example? Smells like "give me the codez" syndrome.

Answer (score 0):

Two Problems:

easy:
`addEventListener` is not supported in IE8 and below, you need to call `attachEvent` (beware, that this has some issues, you need to query the global event object because `this` is not bound to the target here!!).

```
var el = document.getElementById('files');
if (el.addEventListener) {
  el.addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false); 
} else if (el.attachEvent)  {
  el.attachEvent('onchange', handleFileSelect);
}
```

tricky:
The [Filereader API](http://caniuse.com/#search=Filereader) is not available in IE<=9 so you need to work around that using flash or something similar (Silverlight ftw:-D). [Here's a list of shims](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills). There is also a Filereader shim in the list which might work out for you.

In the end it might be the easiest solution to use an already existing multi upload script.

Comment: "please provide details........................................................" means solution details

Comment: in error console it shows that " Object doest not support this property or method (in line 44)".Line no 44 given here "document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect);
"